# Text color change using colspan

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to change color of columns in table using colspan we can change bg-color using colspan.

I am able to change bg-color of columns using colspan and i can change text color but only by using color attribute in every . Is there any way to do it using colspan?

Comment: Can you provide your html and css in your post?

Comment: Show your approach. What did you try ? Attach specific code as a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) along with your question so that everyone can understand your problem clearly.

Comment: `colspan` changes the number of columns that a cell spans. It doesn't change the colour of anything. It's really unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -2):

You can change the background color of **td** or **th** elements with the **colspan** attribute using CSS. To do this, you can use a combination of a class and attribute selector to target the specific elements.

Here's an example of how you can do this:

```css
.custom-table td[colspan] {
 background-color: blue;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<table class="custom-table">
 <tr>
  <td>Hello</td>
  <td>Test Me</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan=2>Colspan Row</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Hello</td>
  <td>Test Me</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

As per your comment my answer is:

No, the `colspan` attribute is used to specify the number of columns that a cell should span horizontally in a table. It does not affect the styling of the content within the cell, including the text color.

To change the text color of a whole column, you can use CSS to target the column by its index and apply a style rule to change the color of the text. For example, you could use the `nth-child` selector to target every cell in a given column:

```css
td:nth-child(2) {
  color: red;
}
```

This would change the text color of every cell in the second column to red.

If you want to change the text color of multiple columns, you can combine the `nth-child` selector with a comma-separated list of column indexes. For example, to change the text color of cells in the second and fourth columns, you could use:

```css
td:nth-child(2), td:nth-child(4) {
  color: red;
}
```

This would change the text color of every cell in the second and fourth columns to red.

Comment: I guess i forgot to add "text" in question...my question is can we change text color of a whole column just by using colspan or change text color in n number of columns just by using colspan.

Comment: I gave you the code and mentioned everything, you can use `color: red;`